# how to load page in div onclick in yii2.0.5

Tags: jquery, yii2

I am using this code to get it done but not able to get it. Popup is opening but page is not loaded in it.

Any one pls help me to get it done.

thanks in advance..

**Script:**

```
$( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

     dialog1=$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({

                          autoOpen: false,

                          height: 600,

                          width: 1000,

                          modal: true,

                                     });

                            $( "#btnAddNewRow" ).on("click", function() {   

                            dialog1.dialog("open");

                            $( "#load-data" ).load("<?php echo Yii::$app-

>request->baseUrl; ?>/country/addcountry");

                                  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Country">

          <div id="load-data"></div>  

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path name seem not correct try using :

```
 $( "#load-data" ).load("<?php Yii::$app->homeUrl . '/country/addcountry' ");
```